# Is it better if the colored winter hats displayed in The 2014 winter hats gallery?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I got several winter hats, so far (e.g. the one I wear now, colored ones).

But it took me some times to make it match with the one displayed in the 2014 winter bash gallery (weird image with blue background).

Is it better if the colored winter hats displayed in [The 2014 winter hats gallery](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/)?

> [image]

Comment: Added screenshot to make it more clear what you're talking about, hope you don't mind?

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for adding that screenshot.

Comment: The blue/white picture represents a box that is partly opened - you can peek inside, but not really see what's in. The colored picture represents a box that already is open.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's better to do that. When a hat is colored in the hats gallery, it means you earned that hat. If *every* hat would be colored, it isn't quickly visible anymore to see which ones you alredy earned.

Comment: Beat me to it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative point of view,

I think that it would be better if the user can see the hats clearly. In accordance with that, colored hats will give a better visibility for the user.

I propose that the colored hats can be seen temporary when the mouse pointer is hovering on top of it. (e.g. wider peek view).

But once again, this is just another point of view. Thanks